# get all elements by class name in polymer

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, polymer-2.x

Can someone please tell me how to get all elements by class name in polymer? We can surely is `this.$$(selector)`, but in the [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom) it is clearly mentioned that `$$ returns the first node in the local DOM that matches selector`.

`

Comment: `this.$$(selector)`  method isn't available at Polymer 2.x. Use this.shadowRoot.querySelector instead.  ref:  https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this.$$()` is a shorthand for `Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector()`.
What you are looking for is the query select all. Which would look like this: `Polymer.dom(parent).querySelectorAll(selector)`
In Polymer 1 this worked. However, I did not test in in version 2. You might have to use this.shadowRoot and wait until the shadow DOM is initialized

You can find further information on that in the [Polymer Documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom) under DOM API & Query selectors

Answer (score 3):

Polymer 1:

Use `this.$$('class-name')` to get the all DOM Elements using the class name.

Polymer 2:

Use `this.shadowRoot.querySelector('class-name')` to get the DOM Elements.

I hope it's helpful to you.

Comment: Ok this works. For selecting all elements just use `querySelectorAll`

Comment: @Kumar , please tell me how can i access class in polymer -3 ??